# Hyperlink on lightning component is throwing an error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, hyperlink

I have below component code to convert the name to hyperlink which will open up its' default record page
component:

```
 <aura:component controller="RaceController">
    <aura:attribute name="race" type="Race__C" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" /> 
    <header class="slds-card__header" >               
        <p class="slds-text-heading--label" >

            <a onclick="{!c.handleClick}"> {!'RaceName: ' + v.race.Name} </a></p>
    </header>
```

controller:

```
handleClick : function (component, event, helper) {
        var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        navEvt.setParams({
            "recordId": component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        navEvt.fire();
    }
```

I want it to open the below page after clicking the hyperlink

[image]

but when I click on the hyperlink **{!'RaceName: ' + v.race.Name}** I get the below error

[image]

and after using the lightning app builder I am getting the below error
[image]

Comment: is component.get("v.recordId") returning a value? doesnt look like it is (maybe im wrong)

Comment: `navEvt` appears to be coming back undefined. Are you running this component inside `one.app`, or using something like Lightning Out, which doesn't support that kind of event?

Comment: I think you are missing force:hasRecordId. You need to implement it to get the record Id.

Comment: Do you want to alter standard lightning component? to convert Name field to hyperlink ?

Comment: @DavidReed I have defined it in a component then iterating it in another component  and finally wrote the component in an app and hitting the preview button

Comment: @RajeshVarmaMudunuri I have implemented the  force:hasRecordId

Comment: is component.get("v.recordId")  rturning a value now?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal name field is now converted to hyperlink but the deal is when I click on it, it gives me an error.

Comment: @glls I have checked console.log and I got this keyword "valueundefined"

Comment: You are running inside lightning experince right? Not in dev console app?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal  I am using developer console

Comment: You might wanna check this... https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/95581/19118

Comment: @PranayJaiswal from the lightning app when I click on the hyperlink it throws an error I have attached the error screenshot

Comment: As @pranay jaiswal said `$A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject")` it is not supported in standalone app .It is only supported in LEX and sales force 1.so only you getting the error above,and  make sure you assigning  `recordId` to the recordId attribute?

Comment: @vignesh I am assign recordId as navEvt.setParams({
            "recordId": component.get("v.recordId")
        })
is ther any alternative way to do the same?

Comment: Yes you are assigning. I mean  you getting a Id value from that attribute ?

Comment: I am getting the name of the attribute and I am keep gettin gan error "Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined"

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, thank you for your responses, it ran successfully on the salesforce1 app but it's not working on the desktop version, is there any alternative way to achieve the same on the desktop version?

Answer (score 1):

Try this? Opens in a new tab.

```
handleClick : function(component, event, helper){
        var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
        window.open('/' + recordId);  
    },
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response but I am using lightning and with the above code it opened up a new tab of classic with the message URL No Longer Exists

Comment: Perhaps there is a page override/redirect in place? Just open the record manually in a browser tab, see how your lightning URL looks like and adjust the string in window.open accordingly. Of course, this will come back biting you IF salesforce decides to change their URL construct. Happened in the recent past.

Comment: I somehow solved the problem, but it works only on salesforce one app, not at the desktop version